# Apply patch as part of a build step in maven

Tags: maven, patch

I have some dependencies that I need to patch. Currently I do the following from a terminal (running ubuntu)

```
patch -R -p1 <Myfolder/Tests/mypatch.patch
```

from the a specified working directory. Now I would like to do this as part of my build in maven. I have tried (based on how "<" should be specified in a xml here: [What characters do I need to escape in XML documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters)):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>apply-patch</id>
                <phase>initialize</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>exec</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <executable>patch</executable>
                    <workingDirectory>../../wdir</workingDirectory>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>R</argument>
                        <argument>p1</argument>
                        <argument>&lt;Myfolder/Tests/mypatch.patch</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </execution>                    
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

but that fails with:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (apply-patch) @ my-project ---
patch: '<Myfolder/Tests/mypatch.patch': extra operand
patch: Try `patch --help' for more information.
```

any ideas?

EDIT: I have now tried with option -i instead:

```
<execution>
    <id>apply-patch</id>
    <phase>initialize</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <executable>patch</executable>
        <workingDirectory>target/tmp</workingDirectory>                         
        <arguments>
            <argument>R</argument>
            <argument>p1</argument>
                <argument>i</argument>                              
                <argument>mypatch.patch</argument>
        </arguments>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

but it gives the error:

```
[INFO] --- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (apply-patch) @ my-project ---
patch: i: extra operand
patch: Try `patch --help' for more information.
```

Here it seems to be possible:

http://security-automation-content-repository.googlecode.com/svn-history/r242/branches/new-shredder/eXist-db/pom.xml

so I guess its just a small detail I am missing, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but there is a plugin specifically made to apply patches: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-patch-plugin/

I'm using it on my current project to patch some classes I generate using JAXB/XJC (also available as a maven plugin) and it seems to work well:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-patch-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <patchFile>${basedir}/src/main/patches/my/package/jaxb-generated-classes.patch</patchFile>
                <targetDirectory>${basedir}</targetDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>patch</id>
                    <phase>process-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>apply</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do stream redirection from the exec plugin but you can pass `patch` the `-i` option to specify an input file instead of having `patch` read from `stdin`.

From `patch` manpage

> -i patchfile or --input=patchfile
>   Read the patch from patchfile. If patchfile is -, read from standard input, the default.

Comment: See the edited post, I have tried with option -i but I get the same error.

Comment: @u123 Try a single `<argument>imypatch.patch</argument>`, instead of separating them as two arguments.